# telegraf on windows, influxdb

Tags: windows, debian, telegraf, influxdb-2

i'm new to telegraf and influxdb, and I tried multiple things. So what I try to achieve, is to monitor 2 windows-based servers where I wanna have the metrics stored on a rock pi where debian 11 is used as os. for testing purpose, I used my personal pc (windows). I installed telegraf as explained in the documentation and I don't get any data into influxdb.

then I tried to install telegraf on my rock pi and this data gets into influxdb. I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong with windows but for me it looks like telegraf isn't working properly on my windows pc or I misconfigured something. when I look in my service manager, I do see the telegraf service running. I already tried mutliple days but still can't figure it out.
I hope someone here can help me in some way. thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you haven't written any of the software in question, and it is not a development tool (software written with the primary goal of being used to write software), your question is off-topic here.  It sounds like network administration, for which there is serverfault.com (But you will need to include some more details or your question will be closed there as well).